# Isolate class to be instantiated only by a specific class: best practices

Tags: c#, optimization

Ok, I am working with 2 layers of class: somekind of a "manager" class which task is to take an object, link all items attached to it, and return it to the caller, and a "data" class which task is to call the database on a specific request.

Here's an example of how I work. Here's a "manager" class:

```
public class CardManager
{
    private static readonly CardData mCardDAL = new CardData();

    public List<CardDisplay> ListCardsToShow(int _pageNumber, string _queryString, string _rarity, string _type, string _color, out int _totalCount)
    {
        List<CardDisplay> listToReturn = mCardDAL.ListCardsToShow(_pageNumber, _queryString, _rarity, _type, _color, out _totalCount);

        LinkListCardDisplayData(listToReturn);

        return listToReturn;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Method links the card set with each cards of the list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_listToReturn"></param>
    private static void LinkListCardDisplayData(IEnumerable<CardDisplay> _listToReturn)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (CardDisplay item in _listToReturn)
            {
                LinkCardDisplayData(item);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static void LinkCardDisplayData(CardDisplay _item)
    {
        _item.mMasterCardID = _item.mMasterCard.mCardID;

        ImagesManager.GetCardImages(_item);

        if (_item.mChildCard != null)
        {
            _item.mChildCardID = _item.mChildCard.mCardID;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a "data" class, namely the `CardData` class in this occurrence:

```
public class CardData
{
    internal List<CardDisplay> ListCardsToShow(int _pageNumber, string _queryString, string _rarity, string _type, string _color, out int _totalCount)
    {
        using (DatabaseEntity db = new DatabaseEntity())
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Open();

            List<CARD> cardData;

            List<CardInfo> listCards;

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_queryString))
            {
                var predicate = GetCardPredicate(_queryString);

                if (_rarity != "All")
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And(_item => _item.CARD_RARTY == _rarity);
                }

                if (_color != "All")
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And(
                            _item => _item.CARD_MANA_COST.Contains(_color) || _item.CARD_COLOR.Contains(_color));
                }

                if (_type != "All")
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And(_item => _item.CARD_TYPE.Contains(_type));
                }

                var cardQry = from c in db.CARD.AsExpandable().Where(predicate)
                              select c;

                _totalCount = cardQry.Count();

                int pageCount = _pageNumber - 1;

                cardData = cardQry.OrderBy(_x => _x.CARD_IDE).Skip(pageCount * 20).Take(20).ToList();

                for (int i = 0; i < cardData.Count; i++)
                {
                    CARD card = cardData[i];

                    if (cardData.Any(_item => _item.CARD_MASTER_IDE == card.CARD_IDE))
                    {
                        cardData.Remove(card);
                    }
                }

                listCards = DataConverter.ListCardDATAToListCardInfo(cardData);
            }
            else
            {
                // If we are here then the user browsed to get the 300 latest entries available.

                Expression<Func<CARD, bool>> cardPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<CARD>();

                if (_rarity != "All")
                {
                    cardPredicate = cardPredicate.And(_item => _item.CARD_RARTY == _rarity);
                }

                if (_type != "All")
                {
                    cardPredicate = cardPredicate.And(_item => _item.CARD_TYPE.Contains(_type));
                }

                if (_color != "All")
                {
                    cardPredicate =
                        cardPredicate.And(
                            _item => _item.CARD_MANA_COST.Contains(_color) || _item.CARD_COLOR.Contains(_color));
                }

                var cardQry = (from c in db.CARD.AsExpandable().Where(_item => !_item.CARD_NAME.Contains("(Foil)"))
                                select c).OrderByDescending(_x => _x.CARD_SET.CARD_SET_RELES_DATE).Take(300);

                cardQry = cardQry.Where(cardPredicate);

                _totalCount = cardQry.Count();

                int pageCount = _pageNumber - 1;

                cardData = cardQry.Skip(pageCount * 20).Take(20).ToList();

                for (int i = 0; i < cardData.Count; i++)
                {
                    CARD card = cardData[i];

                    if (cardData.Any(_item => _item.CARD_MASTER_IDE == card.CARD_IDE))
                    {
                        cardData.Remove(card);
                    }
                }

                listCards = DataConverter.ListCardDATAToListCardInfo(cardData);
            }

            List<CardDisplay> listToReturn = MakeListCardDisplay(listCards);

            return listToReturn;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is not on "how" I do my code (but feel free to make a constructive comment as I love to learn), but rather on how it is structured. I'd like, for example, that a `CardData` class be *exclusively* instantiated by a "manager" class, meaning that I could not, for example, create a `public static readonly CardData mCardDAL = new CardData();` object in a controller.

Is there a way to isolate my class in such a manner that anyone is "forced" to pass through the manager to get the object? And I am working in a good way, is my code good?

Comment: Probably a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to be honest!

Comment: Oh, it seems you are right! Did not know such a place existed. Well, if everyone agrees, I'll move my question over there then.

Comment: Where do you declare `CardData`? If you only want it to be availiable inside your `Manager`, it shouldn't be `public`, but rather encapsulated inside the `Manager` class.

Comment: The class is located in a folder in the same source as the manager. You'd call both class in the same file?

Comment: Im taking about `CardData`'s Access Modifier (`public, internal, private`, etc), Not the physical location.

Comment: Aaah, ok. It's a public class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to deny access from the outside by making `CardData` a nested class inside `Manager`, block it's constructor by making it `protected`, and create a `private` instance class:

```
public class Manager
{
    public class Manager
    {
        CardData c = new CardDataInternal();
    }

    private class CardDataInternal : CardData
    {
        public CardDataInternal()
        { }
    }

    public class CardData
    {
        protected CardData()
        { }
    }
}
```

Comment: ... and then define an ICardData interface so other classes outside of this can work with the CardData object

Comment: @RobertLevy: Not necessary, `CardData` is `public`, so visible to anyone.

Comment: fair enough, posted an alternative answer using interfaces

Comment: I think you might want to revisit your first sentence given that there's now three answers that achieve this in different ways. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can keep both objects public by making the *manager* class a nested class and then give the `Card` class a private constructor (that nested classes are allowed to call), something like:

```
public class Card
{
    private Card()
    {

    }
    public class Manager
    {
        public Card Create()
        {
            return new Card();
        }
    }
}
```

So you can freely create `new Card.Manager()` but the only way to create a new `Card` is via the `Create()` method.

Comment: Note if you do this, convention would be to rename manager to 'factory'

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to @Patrick's approach using interfaces:

```
public interface ICardData { ... }
public class Manager
{
    public class Manager()
    {
        CardData c = new CardData();
    }

    private class CardData : ICardData
    {
        public CardData() { }
    }
}
```

By using interfaces instead of a constructor on a nested private class, you're also set up to do unit testing with mock implementations... probably not important for CardData but if you are doing this on a class that has interesting behavior, it is very important.

Answer (score 1):

From the code provided, it looks like you may want to put the CardData class within the CardManager class and make it private so that only CardManager can access it.

```
public class CardManager
{
    private class CardData { ... }
}
```

Comment: And how would you use `CardData` in the rest of the program?

Comment: You can't with this pattern.  I only suggested this, because he has another type CardDisplay that seems to be what he returns to the rest of his program.  If CardManager really is the only thing to manage CardData then any handling of CardData methods, etc. would be in CardManager.